# (Classic) cycles or multiple cascade paths exception

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
     [ItemId]   int           not null identity(1,1)
    ,[ItemName] nvarchar(250) not null
    -- other colums related to item
)

CREATE TABLE Categories (
     [CategoryId]   int          not null identity(1,1)
    ,[CategoryName] nvarchar(50) not null
    -- other colums related to category
)

CREATE TABLE ItemCategories (
     [ItemId]     int not null
    ,[CategoryId] int not null

    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ItemId], [CategoryId] )
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemCategories_Items] FOREIGN KEY ( [ItemId] )
     REFERENCES Items ( [ItemId] )
     ON DELETE CASCADE --ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemCategories_Categories] FOREIGN KEY ( [CategoryId] )
     REFERENCES Categories ( [CategoryId] )
     ON DELETE CASCADE --ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Classic problem, but it has me puzzled.

[ItemCategories] table is the only table that stores the relationship between [ItemId] and [CategoryId].

All I want is for record(s) to be deleted from [ItemCategories] when a record gets deleted from either [Items] or [Categories].

Can someone else throw their eye over the code to see if I declare something incorrectly? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks fine.

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
     [ItemId]   int not null identity(1,1) primary key
    ,[ItemName] nvarchar(250) not null
    -- other colums related to item
)

CREATE TABLE Categories (
     [CategoryId]   int not null identity(1,1) primary key
    ,[CategoryName] nvarchar(50) not null
    -- other colums related to category
)

CREATE TABLE ItemCategories (
     [ItemId]     int not null
    ,[CategoryId] int not null

    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ItemId], [CategoryId] )
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemCategories_Items] FOREIGN KEY ( [ItemId] )
     REFERENCES Items ( [ItemId] )
     ON DELETE CASCADE --ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_ItemCategories_Categories] FOREIGN KEY ( [CategoryId] )
     REFERENCES Categories ( [CategoryId] )
     ON DELETE CASCADE --ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

go

insert into items(ItemName) values ('itema')
insert into Categories(CategoryName) values ('categorya')
insert into ItemCategories(ItemId,CategoryId) values (1,1)
go
delete from items
go
select * from ItemCategories --empty
```

Comment: That you for looking over my code. That's two people (including myself) now confirming it looks ok. But for some reason when I try to execute it I get that cycles or multiple cascade paths exception. I'll keep looking.